# $confirmation_messages not displaying in Gravity Forms

Tags: php, wordpress, progress-bar, gravity-forms-plugin

I tried searching a question up similar to the one I'm asking here and I could not find one. I apologize if there is already a question like this asked and answered.

What I'm trying to do is replace the Gravity Form progress bar by using my own **html** and **css**. I am able to do this with the `gform_progress_bar` filter provided by Gravity Forms.

The issue I'm running into now is once I finish my entry into the form (which I'm using Ajax with the form), my confirmation is not displaying now. If I comment out the filter and fill out the form, the confirmation displays.

Again what I'm trying to figure out is why my confirmation message is not displaying or how can I retrieve it correctly.

Here is what I have for my code:

```
function request_quote_progressbar( $progress_bar, $form, $confirmation_message ) {

    $output = '';

    $output .= '<div class="meter animate">';
        $output .= '<span class="progress-one">';
            $output .= '<span>';
                $output .= '<div id="percentage">0%</div>';
            $output .= '</span>';
        $output .= '</span>';
    $output .= '</div>';

    $progress_bar = $output;

    return $progress_bar;
} 
add_filter( 'gform_progress_bar_2', 'request_quote_progressbar', 10, 3 );
```

Now when I test this, again my default confirmation does not display but if I comment out the `//add_filter( 'gform_progress_bar_2', 'request_quote_progressbar', 10, 3);` then the default progress bar is displayed with the form and the confirmation message is displayed.

I tried to `error_log( print_r( $confirmation_message, true ) );`but it would come up blank. I even did `error_log( print_r( $form, true ) );` just to see if a confirmation message was there and it is but it is listed like this:

```
[confirmations] => Array
    (
        [58518896a4081] => Array
            (
                [id] => 58518896a4081
                [name] => Default Confirmation
                [isDefault] => 1
                [type] => message
                [message] => Thank you for your request!We are in the process of reviewing your quote and will be in touch with you within the next few days.
                [url] =>
                [pageId] => 0
                [queryString] =>
                [disableAutoformat] =>
                [conditionalLogic] => Array
                    (
                    )

            )

    )
```

Comment: Ok so I got my confirmation message now by doing this: 

I figured out my own issue to get the confirmation message. What I did was below:
`
    $confirmation_message = $form['confirmations'];

    foreach( $confirmation_message as $key => $value ) {
        error_log( print_r( $value['message'], true ) );
    }
`
which printed out my confirmation. So I placed this as my `$confirmation_message` but it is still not displaying the confirmation message when I finish the form.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to just modify the styles from the default progress bar and go from there.